# Javascript move picture to the right where the first goes to the back comes to the front with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am trying to create a JavaScript code that has 3 images up when a button is pushed it looks like they are all moving right. So far I am super lose on the JavaScript part of the code. I can't get it to move, or the button to work.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="switchright.js"> </script> 
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Image Switcher</h1>
<center>
<img src="../images/smile.png" id=smile>
<img src="../images/plain.png" id=plain>
<img src="../images/wink.png" id=wink>
<br>
<button type="button" id=theButton>Switch Right</button>
</center>
</body>
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
theButton.onclick = function pictureChange(){
    document.getElementById('smile').src="../images/wink.png";
}
theButton.onclick = function pictureChange(){
    document.getElementById('plain').src="../images/smile.png";
}
theButton.onclick = function pictureChange(){
    document.getElementById('wink').src="../images/smile.png";
}
```

Comment: Every time you hit the button it is going to keep putting the same image as its src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood - you have 3 images in a row and you want to change their sources circularly by clicking the button.

Hope this helps ( *by the way - I think you should embrace the value of id attribute in double quotes* )

```
    // this will iterate from 0 to 2 and represents 
// the current position of wink
var position = 0;

// save the links to files in an array
var images = ["../images/wink.png", "../images/smile.png", "../images/smile.png"];

// document.getElementById() are expensive in time
// so better to save the references to the objects
// and not find them every click
var smile = document.getElementById('smile');
var plain = document.getElementById('plain');
var wink = document.getElementById('wink');

theButton.onclick = function() {

    // here you now depend on the position values that 
    smile.src = images[position % 3];
    plain.src = images[(position + 1) % 3];
    wink.src = images[(position + 2) % 3];

    // increments the position variable and checks
    // that it deosn't become beggier that 2
    position++;
    if (position > 2) {
        position = 0;
    }
}
```

Please mind that you can change the sources in the `images` array ( if there would be some issues with that ).

Answer (score -1):

Switch the sources in just one function like this:

```js
window.slide = function(){
    var store = document.getElementById('wink').src;
    document.getElementById('wink').src = document.getElementById('plain').src;
    document.getElementById('plain').src = document.getElementById('smile').src;
    document.getElementById('smile').src = store;
}
```

```css
.small {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">Image Switcher</h1>
<center>
<img class="small" src="http://www.costarricense.cr/pagina/radiogigante/index_files/image007.gif" id="smile">
<img class="small" src="http://www.skip-hop.co.uk/images/skip-hop-number-2.gif" id="plain">
<img class="small" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/L3lo.gif" id="wink">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="slide()">Switch Right</button>
</center>
```